# How to read and manipulate a variable from a file with a bat?

Tags: batch-file

What do I want to do:
1. Run a bat file and save its PID in a txt file.
2. Run another bat that reads the previously stored PID from the txt file.
3. The second bat kills the process with the read PID from the txt.

What do I have: In the first main bat:

```
FOR /F %%T IN ('Wmic process where^(Name^="cmd.exe"^)get ProcessId^|more +1') DO (
SET /A ProcessId=%%T) &GOTO SkipLine                                                   
:SkipLine                                                                              
echo %ProcessId%>>ID_MAIN_BAT.txt
```

This works fine, i get the txt file with the PID in it.

What do I have: In the second main bat:

```
FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (ID_MAIN_BAT.txt) do SET /P ID=%i%
taskkill /PID %ID%
```

Result:
The second bat doesent succed to kill the first bat with the stored PID.
Can anyone help me, please?

Full second file:

I dont know, something is wrong, it doesent works. I put here my entire second page code:

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max
title AutoDestroy
color cf
echo.
start "" /min winamp Countdown.mp3
DEL /F Figura1.jpg >nul
TIMEOUT /T 3
taskkill /IM winamp.exe
DEL /F Countdown.mp3 >nul
DEL /F Countdown.bat >nul
DEL /F MainBat.bat >nul
DEL /F AutoDestroy.bat >nul
for /f "delims=" %%a in (ID_MAIN_BAT.txt) do taskkill /PID %%a
```

Comment: 1. in the second `.bat` you also need to double the `%` sign at the `for` variable like `%%i`; 2. the `set` command should read: `set ID=%%i` (also double-`%`, no `/P` switch); as an alternative to the `for /F` loop for reading the file (containing a single ID), you could state `set /P ID=<ID_MAIN_BAT.txt`;

Comment: I got it. I think SachaDee's code (see down) is good for what I am looking for. But it appears to be a problem when it comes t oread from the txt. Is it wrong if in the txt file is (like I said), 4 digit number + space + next row blank?

Comment: Either do a `set /A ID=ID` after reading the file, so `ID` will contain a pure numeric value then only; or, when reading with `for /F`, do not specify options like `tokens`, `delims`, so let `for /F` use the default options...

Comment: ...or even better: in your _first_ batch file, insert parenthesis: `(echo %ProcessId%)>>ID_MAIN_BAT.txt`, to avoid a trailing space to be written to the file...

Comment: Check my edits. You better work with a `Title` and `tasklist`to get the PID or get the value piping it in `findstr /r [1-9]` to get a clean value (if you still want to get it with wmic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First BAT :** Using `Wmic`

```
@echo off & cls
for /f %%a in ('Wmic process where ^(Name^="cmd.exe"^) get ProcessId ^| findstr /r [0-9]') do (
   set "$PID=%%a"
   goto:next)

:next
>ID_MAIN_BAT.txt echo %$PID%
```

**Another and robuster way is to work with a Title in your first BAT to get the PID with Tasklist (so there is no confusion if you have another CMD open):**

**First BAT :** Using `Tasklist`

```
@echo off
title=Test
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('tasklist /v /fo csv ^| findstr /i "Test"') do set "$PID=%%a"

>ID_MAIN_BAT.txt echo %$PID%
```

**Second BAT :**

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (ID_MAIN_BAT.txt) do taskkill /PID %%a
```

Comment: It still doesent work, but i think the cause is the txt file. It contains 4 digits, one blank and a blank row after.

Comment: I do all these so that I could close the main bat file from the second one. I couldnt find a better way that this. If u know how, please advice! :(

Comment: Check my second Edit !

Comment: I dont know what is wrong, it doesent work. I attaced up the netire second bat code. Maybe its a comflict between the instructions somewhere.
Anyway, I appreciate your time!

Comment: Is the ID_MAIN_BAT.txt created with the PID inside (using my second code) ?

Comment: Yes, it is, also with a blank row after.

Comment: I camed up with another solution.
I converted the .bat file in a .exe file.

Now i can actually see MAIN_BAT.exe in tasklist.
BUT:
IF I put this:
taskkill /IM Test_BETA.exe
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process "Test_BETA.exe" with PID 5096.
In cmd appears this and nothing happens. :((((( MAIN_BAT still is open.
MAIN_BAT = Test_BETA

Answer (score 2):

I FOUND OUT why your suggestions didnt worked out.
In my main bat i have the first line:
IF NOT "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit /B
This is for oppening the bat in fullscreen mode, BUT it has a major inconvienent:

IF i delete & exit /B from the end it opens up 2 (two) of the same bat files.
Doing this i realised that the PID writed in the output file belongs to the first procces that is closed by the & exit /B command, and thas why cmd couldnt kill that process, because it was already supressed by & exit /B.

IF i do not put anymore that first line (with fullscreen option) AND IF I convert the bat file into a exe i am able to use TASKKILL /IM MAIN_BAT.exe
AND IT WORKS

Couldnt get it without you, guys, thank you very much!